# User validation failed: email: Path `email` is required

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

when I try to save a user credentials to the mongo database it gives me this error:
"User validation failed: email: Path `email` is required." I don't know why this happens, this problem started occurring to me when I put the validation option of (required: true) I don't know what I'm doing wrong with the code.

here's my schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
   
    
})
```

and this is the user inputs:

```
const newUser = new User({
        firstName: req.body.first_name,
        lastName: req.body.last_name,
        email: req.body.Email,
        password: req.body.password
    })
```

Comment: What's req.body and does it have the Email property? (Maybe it's lowercase 'email'?)

Comment: @mbojko req.body is my html file ```<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required">``` and this is the email input properties

Comment: try email: req.body.email (lower case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try email: req.body.email (lower case)

```js
const newUser = new User({
        firstName: req.body.first_name,
        lastName: req.body.last_name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    })
```